# type has no accessible constructors

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I seem to be having trouble with a class I create. I get the error "type has no accessible constructors" when I try to create an instance of it in the xaml file of a wpf window with the following code:

```
<local:TextStyleDefinition x:Key="deleteItem" StyleName="Delete Notes" ItsId="-1"/>
```

The class TextStyleDefinition is defined as this:

```
public class TextStyleDefinition : BaseStyleDefinition
{
    public string TextFontName { get; set; }
    public string TextSize { get; set; }
    public string TextTabSize { get; set; }
    public int TextBold { get; set; }
    public int TextItalic { get; set; }
    public int TextUnderline { get; set; }
    public string TextWidthFactor { get; set; }

    public TextStyleDefinition() : base()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("TSD ctor : blank");
    }

    // override object.Equals
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null || GetType() != obj.GetType())
        {
            return false;
        }

        TextStyleDefinition lsd = obj as TextStyleDefinition;
        if (this.StyleName != lsd.StyleName ||
            this.ItsId != lsd.ItsId)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    // override object.GetHashCode
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return ItsId;
    }
}
```

And the BaseStyleDefinition class is thus:

```
public abstract class BaseStyleDefinition : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string StyleName { get; set; }
    public int ItsId { get; set; }

    public BaseStyleDefinition() : base() { }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    // override object.Equals
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null || GetType() != obj.GetType())
            return false;
        BaseStyleDefinition rsd = obj as BaseStyleDefinition;
        if (this.StyleName != rsd.StyleName ||
            this.ItsId != rsd.ItsId)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    // override object.GetHashCode
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return ItsId;
    }
}
```

As you can see I have parameterless constructors and the classes are public, so its not the obvious problems. The code compiles fine and executes correctly but VS2015 highlights the line from the xaml as an error and won't show the window in the wpf designer.

Any guesses what it could be?

Comment: I tried your code and it works for me. I use Visual Studio 2015.

From the top of my head - i remember that there was a similar problem with WinForms designer. Did you try adding a default (parameterless) constructor in your TextStyleDefinition  without calling : base() ?

Comment: Can you try removing  `x:Key="deleteItem" StyleName="Delete Notes" ItsId="-1" `. And then slowly add those attribute back one by one ?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why are you calling the `object` constructor in your BaseStyleDefinition?

Comment: ***The code compiles fine and executes correctly*** - so it's just fine. That's a bug in the XAML editor, this was so buggy since VS 2010 and I'm using VS 2012 and still experiencing (and suffering) the editor sometimes but I did not think till VS 2015 it's still buggy like that.

Comment: Try closing the designer, clean your solution, rebuild it and open the designer again. If it still doesn't work, try restarting VS before opening the designer again.